# Where can EU residency permit holders travel to outside the EU?

Tags: eu, schengen, common-travel-area

I am wondering, where can EU residency permit holders travel to outside the EU without a visa? some counties like Mexico for example, allows anyone to visit if they hold a Schengen visa/Schengen state residency permit without obtaining a Mexican visa if their nationality requires a visa to visit Mexico.

So any idea which countries outside the EU can I travel to if I hold a Spanish residency permit for example?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Adding something in the form of: **without an otherwise needed visa** would make it clearer (assuming that is what you mean).

Comment: The question could be phrased more explicitely but the Mexico example explains clearly what it is about. No vagueness and no need to specificy citizenship, that's not the point. There is a related question on travel.SE: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-are-the-non-schengen-countries-that-allow-entry-for-schengen-visa-holders (but it's about Schengen visa holders, not residence permit holders).

Comment: @Relaxed That makes sense. I'll delete my comment. Thanks.